# Query returns result in SQL Server Management Studio, but does not return anything in an application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a query below. It returns data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but does not return anything in an application.

```
SELECT name FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES client, 2) AS Result
```

At the same time query below returns data in both places:

```
SELECT name FROM client
```

Below is the code responsible for query execution:

```
var adapter = Factory.CreateDataAdapter(); // Creates instance of SqlDataAdapter
adapter.SelectCommand = Command; // Contains query in text format

using (var connection = Factory.CreateConnection())
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection;
    connection.ConnectionString = DatabaseSchema.ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();

    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    connection.Close();
}
```

For the first query `dataTable` does not contain any rows, for the second query it contains rows.

User specified in a connection string is the same as I use to authenticate in Management Studio.

Why I am getting such result?

Comment: Show the code where you populate `Command`.. I see no issues in the code you have shown.

Comment: The user principal you're running the queries as might be different in each environment.

Comment: @amy I have only one instance of a database. I tested it with 'sa' user for both scenarios

Comment: i am facing the same, but not sure if related to counted data backup or underlying connection provider

Answer (score 0):

don't use string concatenation and interpolation for query building, instead use Parameterized queries. You cannot forsee problems you may encounter (for instance datatype mismatches). Also your code is subject to Sql Injection attacks.

[Check This for more information about parameterized queries and their use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: The question is not about query building. I simplified my question as much as possible to rid of unimportant details.